# Adobe Flash Extension Directory

Tags: plugins, directory, flash-cs5.5

I installed a Flash extension to Adobe Flash CS5.5 via Adobe Extension Manager CS5.5, but I would like to know where this extension directory is located on my Mac.

Does anyone know where Adobe installed this extension at? I tried the application folder, library folder, and application support folder but still cannot locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This folder is located inside the "Library" folder under your "Home" folder.

Here is the path (on my computer):

Finder > Go > Home (shit+command+H) > Library > Application Support > Adobe > Extension Manager CS5.5 > Configuration > Extensions

If your "Home" folder does not have the "Library" folder, it is hidden and you'll need to open the Terminal and type in this line of console code: `chflags nohidden ~/Library/`

Open the "Home" folder again and you should see your "Library" folder.

Answer (score 0):

/Users//Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Flash CS 5.5/Configuration/_/

To see what files it installed, take a look at Extensions/.mxi in that file.

Comment: Actually that is not the path (at least not on my computer), but I found it. It is hidden and I have to use the terminal to unhidden it. The path to the that folder (on my computer) is Users > username > Library > Application Support > Adobe > Extension Manager CS5.5 > Configuration > Extensions... This Library folder may be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Flash CS6 and mountain Lyon, my extensions were found in:

/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash CS6/en_US/Configuration/Commands